# How to link notes?

Tags: evernote

is it possible to link notes in evernote?

Comment: which version of evernote you using and also which OS

Comment: Duplicate question http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/can-i-link-between-notes-in-evernote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using Evernote since the v2 days and I'm pretty certain this isn't possible in the current V3 flavors.

Much to my continued disappointment.

It would be a brilliant way to get a bit more of a wiki feel to things, wouldn't it? Not to mention the ability to link To Do items to their own notes.

See also: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/can-i-link-between-notes-in-evernote